# Getting 404 error while accessing our web application

Tags: java, apache, spring-mvc, jboss

We are migrating from Jboss4.2 to Jboss7.1.1. We are using Spring 2.5 in our web application. While starting our application we are getting an waring like 
 [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/jshome.htm] in DispatcherServlet with name 'plaksa'.

our application-servlet.xml is contains the following code

```
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

    xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd

                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
                            http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr
                            http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-2.0.xsd
            http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-annotations
            http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-annotations.xsd">

    <!--
            - The controllers are autodetected POJOs labeled with the @Controller
            annotation.
    -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bodhtree.nexus.controller"/>

    <context:annotation-config />
    <!--    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
                    expression="com.bodhtree.nexus.core.system.annotation.SpringBean" />
    </context:component-scan> -->
    <bean id="helloWorld" class="com.bodhtree.nexus.view.HelloWorld">
            <property name="cacheSeconds" value="120" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Do you have any mapping for /jshome.htm  in web.xml or not ?

Comment: Please post your web.xml setting here to review.

Comment: our jboss-web.xml is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC
        "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 2.3V2//EN"
    "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_4_0.dtd">

<jboss-web>
 <context-root></context-root>
    <resource-ref>      
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/databaseName</res-ref-name>
   <jndi-name>java:/jdbc/databaseName</jndi-name>
 </resource-ref>
</jboss-web>

Comment: our web.xml contains <login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
 </login-config>
 <resource-ref>
  <description>DB Connection</description>
  <res-ref-name>jdbc/databaseName</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
 </resource-ref>